# asp.net mvc 404 code error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404

I have project at asp.net mvc. And there is problem i dont know how to solve:
I add at web.config error handling, and that is ok, but it's return

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 157
Location: /Error404.html?aspxerrorpath=/fghdhdfghg
```

which is wrong, i need HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. I have tested at

[that site](Http://www.bertal.ru/index.php?a636586/aurami.ru/fghdhdfghg#h)

Do you know how to set error code for my error404.html page? I have tryed both Hardcoded html page & MVC Action.

Comment: Have you tried disabling custom error handling?

Comment: but i need custom design for that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Response.StatusCode = 404` or you can return a `HttpNotFoundResult` from the controller.

Comment: Does that method allow to use custom design for that page? i got at tester HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, but that has default asp.net design [link](http://puu.sh/1Dv4n)

Comment: yes if you set the StatusCode in your controller before returning the view:

Comment: thancks. but it should be also setted `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` Works now.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the 302 (object moved) because you explicitly requested this in your configuration by telling it to use the alternate page in the case of a 404 error.  Your other choice would be to let the web server send back the 404 error, but you wouldn't have the opportunity to send html content along with it (your whole reason for the redirect, presumably).

Answer (score 0):

302 is not an error. It is the HTTP status code for "moved temporarily," which tells the Web browser / search engine that it should continue using the URL it used in the first place.

A 302 redirect is common when using mod_rewrite, PHP's header() and other such URL-changing schemes. is the caching enabled in your web server..???